# To crawl a website to identify images missing alt text and create a report for the same

Tags: quality-assurance, back-end

There is a scenario where in we need to add `Alt Text` for the images where it is missing in a website.

Used Wave, Light house, Axe tool and also Screaming frog.

The same could be easily achieved using screaming frog however it is a licensed tool because there is no way to do it in free version, where it right away scroll 500 pages and that's it. Cannot make any changes to configuration.

For others have to do it for each page individually and for reporting need to copy paste.

So need assistance if we have any free tool which can crawl the website pages and create a report for images with missing alt text.

Comment: you can use any tool , beautifulsoup python , selenium ,

Comment: If you have access to the page code you can use any linting tool with rule for alt text.